# Matrix containing values of another matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

This is my problem: I have a matrix `A` of order 4 for example (Knowing that I have a very large matrix):

```
        A=[3 4 5 2;
    1 2 4 6;
    3 4 8 7;
    2 4 3 7]
```

and a matrix `B` contains  index rows and columns of the matrix `A`:

```
        B=[2 3 4 1;
    4 3 2 1;
    3 2 1 4;
    4 2 3 1;
    1 2 3 4]
```

I search a vector `C(5,1)` such that:

```
    C(1,1)= A(B(1,1),B(1,2))+A(B(1,2), B(1,3))+A(B(1,3), B(1,4))
    =A(2,3)+A(3,4)+A(4,1)
    C(2,1)= A(4,3)+A(3,2)+A(2,1)
    C(3,1)= A(3,2)+A(2,1)+A(1,4)
    C(4,1)= A(4,2)+A(2,3)+A(3,1)
    C(5,1)= A(1,2)+A(2,3)+A(3,4)
```

So

```
    C=[13;
    8; 
    7;
    11; 
    15] ?
```

I would like to  find a way to make it a clean and optimized way.

Comment: It would have been better if you told us your objective,like a generalized idea...

Comment: i find C from A and B for example :C(1,1)=A(B(1,1),B(1,2))+A(B(1,2),B(1,3))+A(B(1,3),A(1,4)),so C(1)=13

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub2ind` to convert to linear indices

```
szA = size(A);
C = A( sub2ind( szA, B(:,1), B(:,2) ) ) +...
    A( sub2ind( szA, B(:,2), B(:,3) ) ) +...
    A( sub2ind( szA, B(:,3), B(:,4) ) );
```